# Can I make a clickabe image map in geoserver?

Tags: geoserver

I mean when a region of a map (for example, a country) is clicked to redirect me to another URL, not only to give me some information like `fid`,`name`, etc.
You know when a region of a shapefile is clicked below the map is retrieved some information and my question is : would it be possible when the same region is clicked the user to be redirected to another page ?
I am talking about SHAPEFILES not IMAGES(PNG,JPEG,etc) !!
Can this be done?

Comment: Yes, if you configure your source data and WMS layer so that when user clicks a map then GeoServer sends URL as an attribute. You must make your application to read the URL and take care of redicting.

Comment: Please show me how , I would be extremely thankful :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [imagemap](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/imagemap.html) extension to do this. Once you have read the instructions go to http://sourceforge.net/projects/geoserver/files/GeoServer/2.5.2/extensions/geoserver-2.5.2-imagemap-plugin.zip to download the extension. Obviously you will need the version that matches your installed GeoServer.

Comment: Thanks ,for the advice, but I think it would lots of years to mark every region.

Comment: did you read the page linked to? it is an extension that does it for you automatically.

Comment: After reading some information about SLD,my question is : Can SLD do the job with some <Rule> and url tags??

Comment: No sld can't do that which is why there is a plugin.

Comment: When I try to run the .jar file with cmd using java -jar name.jar command I get a respond no main manifest attribute in name.jar.What do I do next ??

Comment: You add the jars to the WEB-INF directory of your geoserver install.

Comment: Yeah, I knew I had to put it in the right directory ,but it still doesn't work.I tried WEB-INF and lib and again with cmd no main manifest !

Comment: Can content.ftl,header.ftl and footer.ftl do the job ??The regions of the map have already been made can't I just configure some settings and throw URL instead of the information below that I normally get?I think it could be done without Image map because the regions are ready and are made.

Comment: Ok I found this:http://fossies.org/dox/geoserver-2.5.2-src/dir_fb61d7ea1ef495342b381f729188f54d.html and what do I do with the files ?

Comment: nothing - just install the plugin, restart geoserver and make a request for the WMS with the right format

Comment: Can you give me your email or at least tell me how to contact you ,because I really need your help ?I downloaded the plugin,executed it (no main manifest) put it into WEB_INF directory.What next ,I am stuck

Comment: I can put you in touch with our sales team to quote a price for training if you would like. Otherwise I'm afraid I can't do direct help.

Comment: OK,finally I can see the Format text/html to appear.Now what should I do next because when I set the format to :text/html in the Request URL I get a blank page ,but no error?